# Normal state of Primary state is Primary

Tags: operator-algebras, von-neumann-algebras

Let $\mathcal{A}$ be a von Neumann algebra. A *GNS-construction* of state $\omega:\mathcal{A}\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ is the representation $\pi_\omega$ on the Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}^{} _ {\omega}$(which is a completion of the quotient space $\mathcal{A}/\mathfrak{J}$, where $\mathfrak{J}$ is a *Gelfand ideal* whose elements satisfying $\omega(X^*X)=0$), defined as $\pi _ \omega (A) [B] = [AB] $ for the equivalence class $[A]$. A state $\omega$ is *primary* if $\pi _ \omega$ is primary, i.e. $\pi _ \omega(\mathcal{A})''$ is a factor(or has trivial center).

A state $\omega_1$ is *in the folium* of representation $\pi _ \omega$ (or *$\pi _ \omega$-normal*) when there is a positive linear form $\rho$ on $\mathcal{H} _ \omega$ such that $\omega_1=\DeclareMathOperator{\Tr}{Tr}\Tr(\rho \pi_\omega (A))$.

In *Local Quantum Physics* by R. Haag, Theorem 2.2.17 in Chapter III says the following:

> (...) (iii) Every state in the folium of a primary representation is primary.

If we consider the folium of a representation is a set of "physical" states(which is given when we fix a single "physical" state), and primary representation as a "representation containing only one irreducible representation type", then the Theorem above makes sense: If a representation basically contains only one irreducible representation, then every "physical" states related to it also need to have the same irreducible representations only, hence it must be primary.

1. Is my understanding here correct? Can I understand the folium of representation and primary representation as above?
2. If so, How can I show this statement rigorously? To show this, I need to take a $\pi_\omega-$normal state $\omega_1$ then show $\pi_{\omega_1}$ is primary. But it is hard to find the relation between the representations $\pi_\omega$ and $\pi_{\omega_1}$ for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following is a rigorous proof of the statement:

Let $\omega$ be primary and $\omega_1$ be given by $\omega_1(A) = \textrm{Tr}(\rho\pi_\omega(A))$ where $\rho$ is a positive trace-class operator on $H_\omega$ of trace 1. Let $\mathbb{B}_2(H_\omega)$ be the space of Hilbert-Schmidt operators on $H_\omega$. There is a natural left action of $\mathbb{B}(H_\omega)$ on this Hilbert space. We observe that this left action induces a representation of $\mathcal{A}$ on $\mathbb{B}_2(H_\omega)$, which we shall denote by $\pi_2$. We note that $\pi_2(\mathcal{A})'' \simeq \pi_\omega(\mathcal{A})''$ since $\pi_2$ is the restriction of the normal left action of $\mathbb{B}(H_\omega)$ on $\mathbb{B}_2(H_\omega)$ and therefore extends to a normal representation of $\pi_\omega(\mathcal{A})''$. In particular, $\pi_2(\mathcal{A})''$ is a factor.

Now, consider the map $i: \mathcal{A} \rightarrow \mathbb{B}_2(H_\omega)$ given by $i(A) = \pi_\omega(A)\rho^{1/2}$. We observe that,

$$\omega_1(A^*A) = \textrm{Tr}(\rho\pi_\omega(A)^*\pi_\omega(A)) = \textrm{Tr}((\pi_\omega(A)\rho^{1/2})^*(\pi_\omega(A)\rho^{1/2})) = ||\pi_\omega(A)\rho^{1/2}||_{HS}^2$$

Hence, $i$ induces an isometric embedding $H_{\omega_1} \hookrightarrow \mathbb{B}_2(H_\omega)$. We observe that this embedding is covariant under the action of $\mathcal{A}$, so we may consider $H_{\omega_1}$, together with the action of $\mathcal{A}$ on it, as a subspace of $\mathbb{B}_2(H_\omega)$. This subspace is invariant under $\mathcal{A}$, so there exists some projection $p \in \pi_2(\mathcal{A})'$ s.t. $H_{\omega_1} = p\mathbb{B}_2(H_\omega)$. This implies that $\pi_{\omega_1}(\mathcal{A})'' = \pi_2(\mathcal{A})''p$. As $\pi_2(\mathcal{A})''$ is a factor, so is $\pi_2(\mathcal{A})''p$, and thus $\pi_{\omega_1}(\mathcal{A})''$ is a factor.

---

The following are some clarifications on why $\pi_2(\mathcal{A})'' \simeq \pi_\omega(\mathcal{A})''$:

We observe that $\mathbb{B}(H_\omega)$ acts on the Hilbert space $\mathbb{B}_2(H_\omega)$ by $S \cdot T = ST$ where $S \in \mathbb{B}(H_\omega)$ and $T \in \mathbb{B}_2(H_\omega)$. One easily check that this is a normal faithful representation so it induces a normal embedding $\pi: \mathbb{B}(H_\omega) \hookrightarrow \mathbb{B}(\mathbb{B}_2(H_\omega))$. (In fact, $\mathbb{B}_2(H_\omega) \simeq H_\omega \otimes \overline{H_\omega}$ and $\pi$ is simply given by $T \mapsto T \otimes 1$.) $\pi_2$ is then simply $\pi \circ \pi_\omega$ and $\pi_2(\mathcal{A}) = \pi(\pi_\omega(\mathcal{A}))$. Since $\pi_\omega(\mathcal{A})$ is weakly dense in $\pi_\omega(\mathcal{A})''$ and $\pi$ is normal, we have $\pi(\pi_\omega(\mathcal{A})'') \subseteq \pi_2(\mathcal{A})''$. But since $\pi_\omega(\mathcal{A})''$ is a von Neumann algebra and $\pi$ is normal, the range must be a von Neumann algebra. The range clearly contains $\pi_2(\mathcal{A})$, so the range must contain the vNa generated by $\pi_2(\mathcal{A})$, i.e., $\pi_2(\mathcal{A})''$. Hence, $\pi(\pi_\omega(\mathcal{A})'') = \pi_2(\mathcal{A})''$. Since $\pi$ is injective, this means it restricts to an isomorphism between $\pi_\omega(\mathcal{A})''$ and $\pi_2(\mathcal{A})''$.

Comment: Thank you for your nice answer. I have some small questions in your answer. (1) For sanity, is the left action-induced representation of $\mathcal{A}$ on $\mathbb{B}_2(H_\omega)$ the one defined on the space $V\equiv \{f:\mathbb{B}_2(\mathcal{H}_\omega)\rightarrow \mathcal{H}_\omega:f(ST)=\pi(S)f(T),S\in\mathbb{B}(\mathcal{H}_\omega),T\in\mathbb{B}_2(\mathcal{H}_\omega)$? (2) I don't get why $\pi_2(\mathcal{A})''\simeq \pi_\omega(\mathcal{A})''$, i.e. their vN algebras are equivalent.

Comment: For the first question, I'm not entirely sure what you meant by "defined on the space $V$". $\mathbb{B}_2(H_\omega)$ is a Hilbert space, so by representing $\mathcal{A}$ on $\mathbb{B}_2(H_\omega)$ I just meant a *-homomorphism from $\mathcal{A}$ to $\mathbb{B}(\mathbb{B}_2(H_\omega))$. It is defined by $a \cdot T = \pi_\omega(a)T$ where $a \in \mathcal{A}$ and $T \in \mathbb{B}_2(H_\omega)$. For the second question, I'll edit my answer to add in some clarifications.